# Changing default network in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have some issues with starting the default network in docker compose. I set all parameters that I want but for some reason, it always says the following:

"services.networks Additional property default is not allowed"

Does anyone have the solution to this?

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:6.8.16
    container_name: elasticsearch
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    networks:
      babel:
        ipv4_address: 172.7.7.5

networks: 
  default:
    name: babel
    driver: custom-driver-1
    config: 
      - subnet: 172.7.7.0/24
        gateway: 172.7.7.1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two places a network section appears in a compose file, at the top level, and within individual services, and the contents of each are not the same. The top level network section defines the network for any service to use, including things like the network name, driver, and config. And the network section within a service indicates which network that service uses and service specific settings, including things like the network alias. The compose file that splits these two for you looks like:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  # services should be defined here, the compose file is invalid without them
networks: # networks indentation moved to top level
  default:
    name: babel
    driver: custom-driver-1
    config: 
      - subnet: 172.7.7.0/24
        gateway: 172.7.7.1
```

Comment: Here is my full docker-compose file in the original post. It won't work even with your solution.

Comment: The error `services.networks Additional property default is not allowed` indicates the indentation of the top level networks section is still not correct and you've placed it within the services section.

Comment: Your full example is also mixing network names, `default` and `babel`. The service network should point to the top level network name `default`, not `babel`.

Comment: How can I rename the default network then?

Comment: @LordM You did rename it, but then you didn't use it.

Comment: So I should've put "default" instead of babel in elasticsearch container?

Comment: @LordM yes, the service network should point to the top level network name `default`, not `babel`.